# Создание exe файла для проекта Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, exe

Я написал проект на IntelliJ IDEA, хотелось бы узнать, как создать исполняемый файл для windows?

Comment: надо запустить `makeForMeExeFile.exe`. данной информации недостаточно, чтобы помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы собираете проект `maven`ом, то можете воспользоваться плагином [`Launch4j`](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/README.adoc)

Как это сделать, расписывать не буду, ввиду громозкости конфигурационных файлов.

Так же, для `java` существует `ahead-of-time` компилятор. Называется он [`Excelsior JET`](http://www.excelsior.ru/products/jet). Опыта работы с ним не имею, но думаю, он делает примерно то, что вам нужно.

Так же, если вы пишете `JavaFX` приложение, то там есть встроенный упаковщик. Он позволяет создать сборки для `linux`, `mac` и `windows` в том числе. Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm).