# Исполняемые файлы Java

Tags: jvm, java

Вопрос такой, если создать .jar или .exe исполняемый файл, он запустится на компьютере на котором нет JVM и не установлены JDK и JRE?

Comment: .jar не запустится, а как вы будете создавать .exe?

Comment: exe - возможно, но только под Windows, так как с JVM он не связан от слова вообще. jar - нет.

Comment: Не знаю насчет _.exe_ (вероятно, зависит от того, как он был создан), но запустить нормально _.jar_ без JRE, который включает в себя JVM, не получится.

Comment: @VladD, .exe можно создать на основе .jar, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @zlotrah так ведь можно сделать, чтобы .exe-файл просто запускал лежащий рядом (или, возможно, даже вшитый в сам .exe) .jar файл, что никак не отменит необходимость использования JRE. А вот если .exe файл полностью заменяет .jar, заменяя байт-код на машинный (надеюсь, я корректно это описал), то это другой разговор.

Comment: @Regent, спасибо за прояснения, сейчас поэксперементирую

Comment: Чисто теоретически, exe может таскать все необходимое с собой, дропать, ставить, настраивать и потом запускать дропнутый jar. Вопрос только в том надо ли так извращаться...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание exe файла для проекта Intellij Idea](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603543/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-intellij-idea)

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, не дубликат, вероятно. Exe'шник тоже может зависеть от рантайма, а тут вопрос именно про то, что рантайм не устанавливать.

Comment: @Qwertiy хм, интересно, не думал об этом. В любом случае то что здесь ответили, дублирует мой ответ на приведенный выше вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. jar в принципе не может работать без JVM (потому что jar - это набор классов в виде байт-кода, а не в виде исполняемых бинарных файлов), то сформулируем Ваш вопрос так: как в один .exe-файл упаковать свой .jar-проект и JVM. Чтобы Ваш проект мог запускаться и работать без предустановки JVM?

На stackoverflow описали успешный эксперимент по скрещиванию [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) и `JVM` (т.е. `JRE`).

Делюсь ссылкой: [как упаковать свой JAR-проект и JRE в один EXE-файл через launch4j](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582064).

Перевожу ответ из ссылки:

1.Упаковать свое приложение и JRE в один ZIP-архив со структурой директорий:

```
containerFolder
|- jre
      |-bin (здесь лежит java.exe из состава JRE)
      |-lib
|- cfg (папка для сохранения user-конфигурации, если нужно)
|- bin (Ваше приложение с .exe и вашим jar-файлом и другими Вашими внешними файлами из проекта)
```

2.В xml-файле для launch4j сконфигурировать JRE таким образом:

```
<jre>
    <path>../jre</path>
    <opt>-DgvSIG.confDir=../cfg</opt>
</jre>
```

Фишка состоит в том, что путь указывается не к файлу java.exe. Путь к java.exe указывается относительно позиции .exe-файла.

В данном примере, в качестве JRE, используется обычная копия стандартного установленного JRE-движка (например: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121).

И да, [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) - бесплатный и с очень демократичной лицензией [BSD 3-Clause License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause).

Answer (score 4):

> Нет, не получится.

Вы хорошо подумали?

Есть такие упаковщики, которые в полученный EXE пакуют версию JRE/JVM, в которой и будет запускаться jar.

Например [ExcelsiorJET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com) - правда, он коммерческий, но если поискать я думаю есть и бесплатные.

Comment: Хм. Интересно, какой размер у полученного exe выходит.

Comment: @VladD, с каких это пор тебя волнует? Времена когда размер RAM был 4k уже канули в лету :)

Comment: Ну, эм, всё же упаковка целой виртуальной машины в EXE выглядит несколько _энтерпрайзно_. :) Плюс разворачивать эту самую виртуальную машину при каждом запуске тоже наверное не вполне бесплатно. Но да, это в общем вполне решение.

Comment: Обожаю такие перлы: *энтерпрайзно* :)

Comment: Действительно интересен размер упакованного небольшого приложения. А точнее, оправдан ли такой кейс для небольших утилит.

Comment: В форумах пишут что размер размер Excelsior RT - 15 мегабайт...

Comment: @VladD, вообще у крупных приложений таскать с собой JRE - стандартная практика.

Comment: @VladD, скорее наоборот. Энтерпрайзные приложения не должны таскать рантайм, его просто потребуют установить. А вот пользовательские - типа Open Office'а или Идеи - таскать могут и будут (правда не знаю, просто ставить при установке, или как-то по-другому с ним разбираться).

Comment: @Barmaley, ExcelsiorJET подходит к задаче, только это не упаковщик, а полноценный AOT-компилятор.

Comment: Кстати, [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/) написан на Java, но запускается везде, значит таскает с собой JVM

Comment: @Qwertiy Android Studio имеет в себе собственную OpenJRE после недавних событий.

Answer (score -2):

Нет, не получится. Есть только одна альтернатива. Некоторые упаковщики в exe, могут привязать его к локальному jvm. То есть вместе с exe придется таскать папку с jre.